# Push Notification it opens my first Activity instead of Activity defined in showNotification() method

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I have a problem and maybe a lot of people happens, well when I try to start activity defined in showNotification method in **MyFireBaseMessagingService** Class

**Important:** *I config my aplication with shared preferences, **IntroActivity(Splash)** is showed just one time*

**Flow Initial:** *IntroActivity(Splash) **->** MainActivity (In default Fragment Option in Navigation Drawer Menu)*

**Second Time run Application:** *MainActivity (In Default Fragment Option in Navigation Drawer Menu)*

I show you my code, I'll really appreciate your help because I need fix this problem, if you need more information, just tell me.

> **Case I (Correct flow)**

When I have application in background, the notification is displayed on taskbar, after I click the notification in top bar, the application is open in the specified activity **DetailNoticiaEventoActivity** with correct information.

> **Case II (Problem flow)**

But when I close the application and finish it, the notification is displayed on taskbar, but when I click it, the application is open in **MainActivity**, and not showing the activity **DetailNoticiaEventoActivity** in first instance how I wanted

> **Case III (Problem flow)**

Sometimes even though the application is in the background, the notification redirects me to the MainActivity

> **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pe.edu.usmp.fiausmp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- SPLASH ACTIVITY -->
        <activity
            android:name="pe.edu.usmp.fiausmp.Activities.IntroActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- END SPLASH ACTIVITY -->

        <!-- MAINACTIVITY WITH NAV DRAWER -->
        <activity android:name="pe.edu.usmp.fiausmp.Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- END MAINACTIVITY WITH NAV DRAWER -->

        <!-- ACTIVITY SHOWED BY NOTIFICATION METHOD -->
        <activity android:name="pe.edu.usmp.fiausmp.Activities.DetalleNoticiaEventoActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- END ACTIVITY SHOWED BY NOTIFICATION METHOD -->

        <!--  FIREBASE CLASS-->
        <service android:name="pe.edu.usmp.fiausmp.Listeners.MyFireBaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name= "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="pe.edu.usmp.fiausmp.Listeners.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!--  END FIREBASE CLASS-->

    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"
        />

</manifest>
```

> **MyFireBaseMessagingService - showNotificationMethod()**

This is my full class, I start a activity with Intent and set PendindIntent with this one. I use getNotification() for show notification on any device, and I use getData() for custom information like Ticker, BigTextStyle and Sound.

**NOTE:** The commented lines, reflects the solutions you tested with the opinions and suggestions of this publication

```
public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

    private static final String TAG = "FIA USMP";

    int contador = 0;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage == null){
            return;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), json);

        }
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, JSONObject json) {

        int cod_not_eve = 0;
        String cod_mod = "";
        String titulo = "";
        String resumen = "";
        String detalle = "";

        try {
            cod_not_eve = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("cod_not_eve"));
            cod_mod = json.getString("cod_mod");
            titulo = json.getString("titulo");
            resumen = json.getString("resumen");
            detalle = json.getString("detalle");

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception2: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetalleNoticiaEventoActivity.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("cod_not_eve", cod_not_eve);
        intent.putExtra("cod_mod", cod_mod);
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        //        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        //        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                //.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(detalle))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                //.setVibrate(new long[] {0, 1000, 200,1000 })
                //.setLights(Color.parseColor("#00BCD4"), 500, 500)
                //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                //.setTicker(titulo);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(contador, notificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("","MyFireBaseMessagingService.sendNotification.contador"+contador);
        contador++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); and remove other two.

Comment: How do you send notifications in the server, cold you add the server code?

Comment: remove `<intent-filter>` from all `<activity>` except for `IntroActivity`. Do not use `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

Comment: I tried all of these solutions, but i get the same errors:
**add intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); and remove other two**

**remove <intent-filter> from all <activity> except for IntroActivity. and I remove PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT**

Comment: David, I send notifications information by java service in json format, but there is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetalleNoticiaEventoActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);    

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: i tried this, but I get the same error, I don't know

Comment: Are you getting notification's response in onMessageReceived() Method?

Comment: yes, I added my onMessageReceived in my post, It is strange, some times the notification open the activity **DetailNoticiaEventoActivity** how I wanted, but some times just opens the initial **interface(MainActivity)**, I need my aplication always opens activity defined in **PendingIntent Intent**

Comment: @GustavoTufiñoFernández i  am getting the same problem . Please tell me if you get any solution for this